# .net StackFrame.GetFileColumnNumber() or GetFileLineNumber() don't return accurate information

Tags: c#, reflection

It seems that GetFileColumnNumber() and GetFileLineNumber() as members of StackFrame do not actually give you the line/column of the function call, but the first character of the line after the previous colon. For example, if you have code that looks like

```
class A {
    A foo() {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace(true);
        StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();

        Console.WriteLine( stackFrames[1].GetFileLineNumber()+":"+
                           stackFrames[1].GetFileColumnNumber());
        return this;
    }
}

A a = new a();
a.foo().  // assume this is line 10, column 4
  foo().
  foo();
```

I was hoping the output would be this, which is the location of the `f` in `foo` for each call

```
10:6
11:6
12:6
```

but instead it turns out to be

```
10:4
10:4
10:4
```

which is the location of the first `a`. This is consistent with the position of breakpoints -- if you try to put a breakpoint on the second or third foo, it shows up on the first foo.

Any idea on how to get accurate line/column information? I've written some self modifying code and I need to find the the right file position. I've been ignoring the column number (which is wrong), but rely on the line number to be accurate. It works if you use semicolons, for example,

```
a.foo();
b.foo();
c.foo();
```

The ILoffset does change for each call to foo... I wonder if there is another way to map IL offset to source code?

Comment: This info is recorded by the compiler this way in the PDB file.  You can ask for a change at connect.microsoft.com but that's certainly not going to help you anytime soon.  You'll have to live with this restriction.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the position is recorded at the statement level.

In your first example,

```
a.foo().foo().foo();
```

is the statement, whereas in your second example you have three separate statements.